# Let U be open and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be partial differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

The Assignment:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be partial differentiable and let all partial directional derivatives be continous function on $U$. Show that for $x \in U$: The directional derivative $D_vf(x)$ exists for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0\}$ and $$D_vf(x) = \langle v, \nabla f \rangle$$
>   ($\langle x,y \rangle$ denotes the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ $ \langle x,y \rangle := x_1y_1 + ...+x_ny_n $)

I'd really appreciate a hint or two.

Comment: Your course/text presumably has a theorem that tells you that if the partial derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable (in the sense that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your course/text presumably has a theorem that tells you that if the partial derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable (in the sense that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),h\rangle}{\|h\|} = 0.$$
Then substitute $h=tv$ and let $t\to 0$ to get the definition of the directional derivative.